# Git Pull: Change Authentication

Tags: linux, apache, git

I'm quite new to git. I have a repo setup on a server (A) where access is via ssh rsa keys. I have a few users there including myself. Now I do `git clone` on my local machine and get a local copy, make changes, and `push origin master`, everything works fine.

The problem I'm experiencing is that our testing server (server B) already has everything setup and what I'd like to do is pull my latest changes to that server. The testing server has also got several users, as well as `www-data` as the owner of the whole directory (running Apache).

When logging in via SSH using my name, I cannot `git pull`, says .git is locked, so I do `sudo git pull` which asks me the password for a different user (user1). I do not know that password and I'd like to remove that user completely, but before I do, I have to switch the git repo on the testing server to pull changes using MY authentication (kovshenin) and not user1's.

What's the correct way to do that? I wouldn't like to remove everything and start from a fresh clone, since it has some local changes.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After three hours of searching and playing I have found the answer myself. The authentication details are stored in the `.git/config` file under the `url` setting in the `[remote "origin"]` section.

Comment: Well, you can use the command 'git remote -v' to show the current remote configuration and do a 'git remote set-url ssh://you@location...' No need to edit config files directly

Comment: I needed to add 'origin':  git remote set-url origin https://usera@....

Answer (score 1):

To me. If the issue is changing authentication from https to ssh *(https kind of no longer works anyway)*, I do:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:etc/etc.git
```